# BackHandler.exitApp() doesn't shut down app, just closes it

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am creating an app with an android emulator and React Native. I want to close/restart the app when you click a button. I am using `BackHandler.exitApp()` to accomplish this. However, when the button to close the app is clicked, it just closes the app but doesn't actually shut it down. Is this what it is supposed to do? What command should I use instead to completely shut down the app?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, according to Google, you're never supposed to completely quit an app programmatically, the user may think it "crashed" or "glitched".

Make sure that your app is not for iOS! Apple will reject an app if it programmatically quits!

Second, there is no command to completely shut down the app that is native to React Native.

Additionally, `BackHandler.exitApp()` does *not* close your app in any way, nor should it. It is designed to simply send it to background.

There are some libraries that can get around this, E.G. [react-native-exit-app library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exit-app) on npm. Then you would use the code

```
import RNExitApp from 'react-native-exit-app';
...
RNExitApp.exitApp();
...
```

to exit the app fully, if that is what you desire.

Comment: The "react-native-exit-app" library doesn't shut down the app, it just closes it the same as BackHandler.exitApp() .

Comment: If you follow the link, the first thing you'll see as the description of the package is:
"Exit / Close / Kill / shutdown your react native app. Does not invoke a crash notification."

Comment: I'm saying because I tried the library and it only closes the app without killing it.